# Сравнение дат разных форматов

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Описание проблемы:
У меня есть две таблицы в *SQLite*: `car_disp` и `car_move`, содержащие даты в разных форматах.

В таблице `car_disp` дата рождения `date_birth` представлена в формате **`YYYY-MM-DD`**, в то время как в таблице `car_move` дата заказа `date_take` использует формат **`DD.MM.YYYY`**.

Мне нужно выбрать записи, где месяц и день даты рождения совпадают с месяцем и днем даты заказа. 
Кроме того, заказы должны быть приняты в первой половине дня, то есть до полудня.

Я попытался использовать `substr` для извлечения и сравнения дат, но запрос не работает.

Вот мой текущий запрос:

```
SELECT cd.disp_id, cd.full_name
FROM car_disp cd
JOIN car_move cm ON cd.disp_id = cm.disp_id
WHERE substr(cd.date_birth, 6, 2) || substr(cd.date_birth, 9, 2) = substr(cm.date_take, 4, 2) || substr(cm.date_take, 1, 2)
AND substr(cm.time_take, 1, 2) < '12';
```

Проблема в том, что я получаю пустой результат или некорректные данные. 
Хотел бы узнать, как правильно формировать запрос в *SQLite* для сравнения даты и времени в таком контексте.

UPD: Запрос рабочий, но я невнимательный. Перепутал 1 символ в названии столбца

Comment: Судя по всему, эти"даты" на самом деле строки. Нужно перевести их в настоящие даты и тогда уже сравнивать обычным способом.

Comment: Решил. Проблема была в моей невнимательности. Прошу прощения) Я перепутал 1 символ в названии столбца, и ломал голову несколько часов.

Comment: [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)